# Laravel Eloquent WHEREIN Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, where-in

I am a beginner to the Laravel framework. In this case, I have used Eager Loading. Also, I have assigned data to a Variable called $articles. After that, I have used **WHERE IN** Condition to fetch related data. Finally I have returned **$articles** variable. Below, there is my code. But Unfortunately, my code is not working properly. Are there any solutions for this? Thank You!

```
$categories=$request->categories  == null ? null:$request->categories;
$articles=Article::select(['id','title','published_date','cover_image','slug','keywords','meta_description','language','author_id','editor_id','category_id','status_id'])
        ->with(['category:id,category_name','language:id,language_name','status:id,status_name','editor:id,name','author:id,name']);

 if($categories!=null)
  {
                    
     $articles=$articles->wherein('category_id',$categories);
  }
```

Comment: Dont't post images of code, post the code in a code block in your question, also, define what the error/problem is.

Comment: Please add your code line, as what is $categories variable we don't know. By the way, $categories should be an array as whereIn() accept an array as the second parameter. Looking at your if the condition it looks you are passing some value.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `get()` from the top query, put it after your `whereIn`:

```
$articles = $articles->get();
```